# How can I control my for loop

Tags: for-loop, find

I am working on a simple program to determine if a user's input is in a predefined array of 8 characters. If it is, then it should print out the letter and its position. If not, it should say that it doesn't exist.

The issue is that  it looks through the array and finds the character, then goes to the else and prints out that it "doesn't know" where it is for the 7 remaining positions because of the for loop. I traced the variables and conditions on paper, and while I somewhat understand why the problem occurs, I don't really know how to solve it.

So far I've tried breaking the loop, creating a boolean that would change if the character was found and print the information out (still the issue of it going to the else and printing 7 times that it can't find it).

```
char search;
char tryAgain='Y';
char arrayChar[]= {'a', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y'};

while(tryAgain == 'Y')//while user enters Y
{   
    System.out.println("\nEnter a character to check if it is present in the array");
    search= input.nextLine().charAt(0);//extract first letter

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayChar.length; i++)//looks through
    {   
        if(search == arrayChar[i])//if it is found      
            System.out.println(search + " was found in the " + i +" position\n");//print that it is
        else
            System.out.println("Cannot find the character");
    }

    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Yes/No?");
    tryAgain= input.nextLine().charAt(0);
}//while try again

System.out.println("Thank you come again");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print `Cannot find` when your loop is done. Like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Example
{
    public static void main(String args []){
        char search;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        //get user input for a
        char tryAgain='Y';

        char arrayChar[]= {'a', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y'};


        while(tryAgain == 'Y')//while user enters Y
        {   
            boolean verify = false;
            System.out.println("\nEnter a character to check if it is present in the array");
            search= input.nextLine().charAt(0);//extract first letter

            for(int i = 0; i < arrayChar.length; i++)//looks through
            {   

                if(search == arrayChar[i])//if it is found      
                {
                    verify = true;
                    System.out.println(search + " was found in the " + i +" position\n");//print that it is
                }


            }
            if(verify == false){
                System.out.println("Cannot find the character");
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Yes/No?");
            tryAgain= input.nextLine().charAt(0);


        }//while try again

        System.out.println("Thank you come again"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the else statement out of the for loop, because every time it looks through the "i" in the for statement and not find the character it will print the "else", so the "else" should be like that:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < arrayChar.length; i++) {  

      if(search == arrayChar[i])    

            System.out.println(search + " was found in the " + i +" position\n");
    }       
      else 
                System.out.println("Cannot find the character");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your "else" is in the wrong place, and

2) you could use a "break" from the "for()" loop:

```
    char search;
    char tryAgain='Y';
    char arrayChar[]= {
      'a', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y'
    };

    //while user enters Y  
    do { 
      System.out.println("\nEnter a character to check if it is present in the array");
      search= input.nextLine().charAt(0);//extract first letter

      //looks through
      boolean found = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < arrayChar.length; i++)h {   
        if(search == arrayChar[i]) {  
          System.out.println(search + " was found in the " + i +" position\n");
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      } 

      if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find the character");
      }

      System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Y/N?");
      tryAgain= input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    } while(java.lang.Character.toUpperCase(tryAgain) == 'Y');

    System.out.println("Thank you come again");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, do you need stop internal loop when found it or continue if doesn't?.

Try this:

```
    char search;
    char tryAgain = 'Y';
    char arrayChar[] = { 'a', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y' };
    boolean found = false;
    int position = 0;

    while (tryAgain == 'Y')// while user enters Y
    {
        System.out
                .println("\nEnter a character to check if it is present in the array");
        search = input.nextLine().charAt(0);// extract first letter

        found = false;
        position = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayChar.length; i++)// looks through
        {
            if (search == arrayChar[i]) { // if it is found
                found = true;
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found) {
            System.out.println(search + " was found in the " + position
                    + " position\n");// print that it is
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes/No?");
            tryAgain = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot find the character");
            System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Yes/No?");
            tryAgain = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        }
    }// while try again

    System.out.println("Thank you come again");
```

.Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of errors, at least on my PC. Your "else" statement is good but the implementation is wrong, which gives the "Cannot find" after a "FOUND" letter, and here's the working code:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.*;;

    public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char search;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char tryAgain='Y';
    char[] arrayChar = new char[] { 'a', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'r', 't', 'u', 'y' };
    boolean flag = false;

while(tryAgain == 'Y')//while user enters Y
{   
System.out.println("\nEnter a character to check if it is present in the array");
    search= input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayChar.length; i++) {  
        if(search == arrayChar[i])    {
            flag = true;
            System.out.println(search + " was found in the " + i +" position\n");
            break;
```

You needed a break here if the for loop found the char, and before it looped through the for loop even after finding the char which will not match the other ones and go to the else statement, and then printed the else statement you had.

```
        }
        else {  flag = false;   }
    }
    if(flag == false){
            System.out.println("Cannot find the character");
            //flag = true;
    }

    System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Y/N?");
        tryAgain = Character.toUpperCase(input.nextLine().charAt(0));
        //while user enters Y or y

}//while try again

System.out.println("Thank you come again");
    }
}
```